# ReactJS. calling a function from an outside variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm new to ReactJS and trying to make a small web application.
I have a list of items to put in a sidebar, and I want each item to give back a status tu the sidebar when clicked (so that I can style the active link accordingly).

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SideBarItem from "./SideBarItem";

const items = {
    'DASHBOARD' : 'home',
    'Utenti': 'user',
    'Corsi' : 'education',
    'Logistica' : 'check',
    'Comunicazioni': 'bullhorn'
};

const listItems = Object.entries(items).map(([key,value])=>{
    return <SideBarItem 
                onClick={this.changeState(key)} active={this.state.active == key ? 'active' : ''} 
                title={key} 
                glyph={'glyphicon glyphicon-' + value.toString()}/>
});

class SideBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {active: 'DASHBOARD'};
}

    changeState (row) {
        this.setState({
            active: row
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id = "sidebar" className="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar paper-depth-1">
                <ul className = 'nav nav-sidebar'>
                    {listItems}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default SideBar;
```

But this code is returnig the following error:

```
TypeError: _this.changeState is not a function
```

I understand that there's something wrong in calling a component function from an outside variable, but I don't get how can I make this work in any other way.

Comment: Normally you'd pass the function into the component, but the way it's organized now what you're trying to do will be trickier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the list of items in `render()`, the `this` scope will be the component instance, as you need it to be.

```
class SideBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {active: 'DASHBOARD'};
    }

    changeState(row) {
        this.setState({
            active: row
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="sidebar" className="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar paper-depth-1">
                <ul className="nav nav-sidebar">
                    {Object.entries(items).map(([key,value]) =>
                        <SideBarItem 
                            onClick={() => this.changeState(key)}
                            active={this.state.active == key ? 'active' : ''} 
                            title={key} 
                            glyph={'glyphicon glyphicon-' + value.toString()}
                        />
                    )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the compile error is gone!
I honestly didn't think about doing that...
Now the page renders, but the state isn't changing onClick...